# FBLikeControl does not open Facebook app

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-like, facebook-ios-sdk

I have implemented [FBLikeControl](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/like-button/) on ios. Now if I login to app with Facebook login and Facebook app is installed in my device it always opens page in Safari instead of Facebook app.

I have used following code for the like

```
FBLikeControl *like = [[FBLikeControl alloc] init];
like.likeControlHorizontalAlignment = FBLikeControlHorizontalAlignmentCenter;
like.objectID = @"https://www.facebook.com/***my page***";
like.objectType = FBLikeControlObjectTypePage;
like.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = 400.0f;
like.likeControlStyle = FBLikeControlStyleBoxCount;
[self.view addSubview:like];
```

Comment: What version of the FB app do you have? FBLikeControl will only open the FB app if you have a supported version.

Comment: @MingLi I am using v3.21.1 released on December 5

Comment: Not the SDK version, but the Facebook app version.

Comment: @MingLi Working fine after updating FB app. Thanks for support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by @MingLi, FBLikeControl will only open the Facebook app if supported version is available on device.